# Base de un cilindro en Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

estoy tratando de graficar un vaso con forma de cilindro en matplotlib, pero no he encontrado ninguna forma de graficar la base de este.
hasta ahora he hecho esto, perdon por el desorden :)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# grid del cilindro
x=np.linspace(-1, 1, 200)
z=np.linspace(-2, 2, 200)

z1=np.linspace(-1, 0, 200)
x1=np.linspace(0, 1, 200)

x2=np.linspace(-1.2, 1.2, 200)
z2=np.linspace(-1.2, 1.2, 200)

Xc, Zc=np.meshgrid(x, z)
Yc = np.sqrt(1-Xc**2)

Xd, Zd=np.meshgrid(x,z2)
Yd = np.sqrt(1.2-Xd**2)

Xe,Ye=np.meshgrid(x1,z1) 
Ze=-2+Xe*0+Ye*0 #z


# Plot del cilindro en Varias partes
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")

ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc, Zc, alpha=0.4, color='blue',rstride=6, cstride=12) # Mitad delantera
ax.plot_surface(Xc, -Yc, Zc, alpha=0.4, color='blue',rstride=6, cstride=12) # Mitad trasera

ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yd, Zc, alpha=0.4, color='blue', rstride=6, cstride=12) # Mitad delantera interna
ax.plot_surface(Xc, -Yd, Zc, alpha=0.4, color='blue',rstride=6, cstride=12) # Mitad trasera interna

ax.plot_surface(Yd, Xc, Zc, alpha=0.4, color='blue',rstride=10, cstride=10) # Mitad delantera interna 2
ax.plot_surface(-Yd, Xc, Zc, alpha=0.4, color='blue',rstride=10, cstride=10) # Mitad trasera interna 2

ax.plot_surface(Xe, Ye, Ze, alpha=0.2, rstride=10, cstride=10) # base inferior
ax.plot_surface(-Xe, -Ye, Ze, alpha=0.2, rstride=10, cstride=10) # base inferior 2
plt.show()
```

He estado tratando de aplicar formulas de circulos de distintas formas pero ninguna me ha resultado hasta ahora.
Se agradecen las respuestas :).

Answer (score 1):

Llegue tres años y medio tarde, pero si alguna otra persona necesita hacer lo mismo aquí les dejo el código que desarrolle, primeramente uso coordenadas polares y después lo pase a cartesianas; en mi caso, necesito generar el cilindro completo, si solo requieren la tapa inferior (junto con el cilindro) basta con eliminar la lista `[X_t, Y_t, Z1_t]` en el `return`.

Notas:

1. He desarrollado una función, la cual retorna una lista de listas; las listas interiores contienen los parámetros que necesita `plot_surface()` para graficar, primero se debe crear el objeto donde se graficara y después mediante un bucle se van anexando los gráficos de la lista retornada.
2. El cilindro es paralelo al eje Z
3. `x0, y0` son el centro del cilindro
4. `r` es el radio del cilindro
5. `z0, z1` definen la altura del cilindro

```
def cyl(x0, y0, r, z0, z1):
    edge = 11   # Número de vértices->caras-1 para graficar la superficie la superficie

    #-------Radio, ángulo phi y altura de la ecuación en cilíndricas; e: ecuación
    r_e = np.linspace(0, r, edge)
    p_e = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, edge)
    z_e = np.linspace(z0, z1, edge)

    #-------Mallados para las tapas y el cilindro; t: tapa, c: cilindro
    R_t, P_t = np.meshgrid(r_e, p_e)
    R_t, Z_c = np.meshgrid(r_e, z_e)

    #-------Coordenadas cartesianas del cilindro para graficar
    X_c = r*np.cos(p_e)+x0
    Y_c = r*np.sin(p_e)+y0

    #-------Asignamos la altura de los puntos a graficar en Z
    z0_lambda = lambda x: z0*(x+1)/(x+1)   # x+1 para que no dé problemas con la evaluación en 0/0
    z1_lambda = lambda x: z1*(x+1)/(x+1)
    
    #-------Puntos en Z
    Z0_t = z0_lambda(R_t)
    Z1_t = z1_lambda(R_t)

    #-------Pasamos el grid a cartesianas para las tapas
    X_t, Y_t = R_t*np.cos(P_t)+x0, R_t*np.sin(P_t)+y0

    return [[X_c, Y_c, Z_c], [X_t, Y_t, Z0_t], [X_t, Y_t, Z1_t]]
```

La forma en que lo gráfico es la siguiente

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

cilindro = cyl(3,3,4,-6,2)

for i in range(len(cilindro)):
    ax.plot_surface(cilindro[i][0], cilindro[i][1], cilindro[i][2], color='blue')

plt.show()
```

Esto genera un cilindro centrado en (3,3) de radio 4, base en -6 y altura en 2, como en el siguiente gráfico:
[image: Cilindro completo]

Si le quitamos la lista `[X_t, Y_t, Z1_t]` en el `return` (que señale en el primer párrafo), se obtiene:
[image: Cilindro sin tapa superior]

Espero les sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

encontre esta funcion en internet y ya me funciono agregandola al final, se las dejo por si a alguien le sirve

```
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, PathPatch
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d

p = Circle((0, 0), 1.1)
ax.add_patch(p)
art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=-2, zdir="z")
```